# extract first 3 lines with uniq values from CSV file

Tags: linux, csv, command-line-interface

I have a large CSV file, I want to sort it by column2 and column3 and take only the first 3 lines having unique values from column2. So I search for something like:

sort -k2,2 -k3,3 -u2,2-3 (the -u2,2-3 part is not existing in reality).

Any idea how to do it on commandline without writing a program on my own?

Comment: _"without writing a program on my own?"_ you'll end in writing program for CLI (which will be executed by bash)

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but I think this will work.

**Assumptions:**

1. Your file is named `$FILE`.
2. The file contains only digits separated by commas.

**Code:**

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } !/^$/ { print NR,$2,$3 }' < $FILE |
    sort -nk 2,3 |
    awk '{ print $1,$2 }'
    uniq -uf 1 |
    head -n 3 |
    while read num ignore; do sed -n "${num}p" < $FILE; done
```

**Line-by-line explanation:**

1. `awk:` Print the line number and fields 2 and 3 of all non-blank lines in the file. Later, we'll use the line number as an index to extract the desired lines from `$FILE`, after we've sorted on fields 2 and 3.
2. `sort:` Sort the output numerically by fields 2 and 3.
3. `awk:` Remove field 3, leaving only the line number and field 2.
4. `uniq:` Print only the lines that are unique, ignoring the line number.
5. `head:` Print only the first 3 lines.
6. `while:` Read the 3 line numbers, ignoring the remainder of each line. Print that line from the original file.